# How to use format specifiers with strdup?

Tags: c

How to use format specifier with strdup?
I am trying to do something like this.

```
char arr[10] = "acbde";
char* s = strdup("Hello..I am %s", arr);
```

But this does not work.

Comment: `strdup` is used to duplicate a string, not to format it. You probably wanted `snprintf`.

Comment: Library functions like `strdup` are liberally documented. You don't have to guess at how they work. I suggest you look at the documentation.

Comment: Or the Linux-specific `asprintf`, which allocates a string.

Comment: @moehm: agreed but its not limited to linux: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man3/asprintf.3.html

Answer (score 6):

You can't use the function `strdup` for this. Instead you should use `snprintf`. Here is a basic example on how you should do it.

```
char *arr = "acbde";
char str[100]; // set this to your maximum length

snprintf(str, sizeof(str), "Hello..I am %s", arr);
```

Here is a more complete example on how it can be used.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>

int main(void) {
  char *arr = "acbde";
  char *str;

  int length = snprintf(NULL, 0, "Hello..I am %s", arr);
  assert(length >= 0); // TODO add proper error handling
  str = malloc(sizeof(char) * (length + 1));
  snprintf(str, length+1, "Hello..I am %s", arr);

  printf("%s [%d]\n", str, length);
  free(str);
}
```

Comment: @szczurcio thanks, I'll think about that next time I answer :)

Comment: Don't hardcode the buffer length, use `sizeof(str)` as the second argument to `snprintf`. Also, nitpick, but there's no point allocating `arr` on the stack here (with wrong length).

Comment: @szczurcio I originally put a define MAX_LENGTH in there and quickly replaced it with 100 for the sake of simplicity.

Comment: Yes, that's what the OP is looking for. If you want to mimic the `dup` behaviour, where the result is allocated on the heap, you can run `snprintf` twice: It returns the untruncated length of the string, so you can call it with zero length and a null buffer once to find out the required space, allocate accordingly and then do the printing on the allocated buffer.

Comment: Using `snprintf()` to prevent buffer overflow solves _a_ problem. Yet not checking the result of `snprintf()` causes another.  Best to show testing the result of `snprintf()`. Something like `int n = sprintf(...); if (n < 0 || n >= sizeof str) Handle_error()`.

Answer (score 3):

Try use `g_strdup_printf()`.
But should understand - you must free memory after using this function.